# Changing colours in the table of contents with unnumbered sections

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, books

I think is a crash between the packages unnumberedtotoc and tocloft... I want a table of contents with a black background, white font and unnumbered sections... But I can't have no idea how make the unnumbered sections works with the white font... This is how i'm trying:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline  
\newcommand{\nopagecontentsline}[3]{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\fontsize{42pt}{0pt}\bfseries\color{white}}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\huge\bfseries\color{white}}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\huge\bfseries\color{white}}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\huge\bfseries\color{white}}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip10pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip20pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{3,5cm} 
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\tableofcontents
\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\clearpage  
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\contentsline\protect\nopagecontentsline}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\contentsline\protect\oldcontentsline}
\section{Name of unnumbered section}
Text
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work... If i remove the unnumbered sections with a standard "\section" it works but the sections are numbered. My other try was:

```
\begingroup
\color{white}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
```

But it works for everything except the section name that stays black...

Edit:

Now trying "\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}" to remove section numbers instead of "unnumberedtotoc"... The first code still doesn't work, and the second still makes everything except the titles white. New version edited.

Comment: I can't compile your MWE. What is the `unnumberedtotoc` package; it is not on CTAN. Have you tried `\section*{Unnumbered}` `addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered}` ?

Comment: unnumberedtotoc Is a package on github... I'm not using it anymore, but using \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} with standard \section{XXX} ... It still makes everything except the title names white...

Comment: The `titletoc` package allows for different commands for the formatting of numbered and unnumbered sections.

Comment: Sorry, my MWE is working... I'm a moron, and the reason why wasn't working for me was because I had hyperref with "linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black,"...